# How do I set up RewriteRule for urls that all start with the same folder and then some but not all subfolders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rule to redirect some but not all of the content of a certain folder:

- ^folder1/ any .html files
- ^folder1/blackberry
- ^folder1/content
- ^folder1/data
- ^folder1/images
- ^folder1/docs

I need to use RewriteRule to send everything except ^folder1/blackberry to another site (eg, http://somedomain.com/main.html) and I'm sure there must a way to do this with regular expressions but I don't (yet) know how :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rule to catch everything and exclude the exceptions with a `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/blackberry$
RewriteRule ^folder1/ http://sub.example.com/main.html [L,R=301]
```

This rule redirects every request with a URL path that starts with `/folder1/` except `/folder1/blackberry` externally to `http://sub.example.com/main.html`.

Comment: Sweet. I just changed it to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/blackberry/$
so that the blackberry folder doesn't redirect. Without the end slash, it did still redirect that folder, although subfolders of blackberry were fine. 
Thanks so much.